# Error in gem: uninitialized constant Item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I'm wanting to delegate a method to a separate class and have the following main file for the gem:

```
require "content/version"
require "content/models/item"
require "content/models/category"
require "content/transformer"
require "content/service"
require "content/presenter"
require 'active_support/core_ext/module/delegation'

module Content
  extend self
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegator :Item, :find, :find
  def_delegator :Item, :find_multiple, :find_multiple
  def_delegator :Category, :find, :find_category
end
```

`require "content/models/item"` is defined as such:

```
require "active_support"
require "active_model"
require "content/service"

module Content
  class Item
    include ActiveModel::Model

    [...]

    def self.find_multiple(*keys)
      items = content_service.items(keys.flatten.compact.uniq)
      items.map {|item_params| as_model(item_params)}
    end
  end
end
```

Any thoughts as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What's the backtrace? What line is referencing the constant `Item`?

Comment: @NathanWallace backtrace is `NameError - uninitialized constant Item:
  app/presenters/recommends/recommends_presenter.rb:7:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/recommends/recommends_controller.rb:14:in `new'
  app/controllers/recommends/recommends_controller.rb:14:in `recommends_presenter'
  app/controllers/recommends/recommends_controller.rb:7:in `recommends'`

And the Item is being referenced via a call to `Content.find_multiple([...])`

Comment: What's line 7 of `app/presenters/recommends/recommends_presenter.rb`?